# Вывод значений php скрипта в форму

Tags: php, html, css

Есть html страница, в которой выполняется скрипт по нажатию на кнопку(происходит проверка переменной и если не пустая, то выскакивает форма ввода данных и по нажатию на кнопку отправки происходит отправка формы на саму себя и на экране отображается вывод через echo).Как можно реализовать вывод в реальном времени(тем же echo&fluck()) результатов работы этого скрипта в форму на этой же html странице, через какой-нибудь  или ?По идее если я каждый раз буду в echo php скрипта прописывать создание формы, то у меня каждый раз будет создаваться новая, а мне надо передавать данные заранее уже созданному полю для вывода в него.Как это можно реализовать?
Пример того где должна быть форма:

```
<?
if(!empty($_POST['author'])) {
....
тут мой код, кучи циклов и в конце echo переменной
....
} else {
?>
<form action="имя-этого-же-скрипта.php" method="post">
    Введите автора: <input type="text" name="author" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправь меня!" />
</form>
[_____________________]
<?
  }
?>
```

Comment: `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />` если я правильно понял

Comment: Это нужно прописывать просто вне скрипта, под формой?Или вместо базового echo  в самом скрипте?

Comment: Выложите свой код, так сложно сказать. Я лишь показал как вывести данные переменной в текстовом поле.

Comment: @Геннадий-Журов 
Дополнил свой вопрос примером кода.
Мне нужно чтобы вместо [_____________________] появлялось поле и в него делался вывод с echo.Там около 30-40 строк должно быть.Сейчас же я наблюдаю пустой экран и тупо вывод в echo столбиком, с исчезновением всех полей и кнопок.